# Pandas - Convert two columns into a new column as a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Pandas to convert two columns into a column that is a dictionary representation of the two converted columns.

```
df = DataFrame({'Metrics' : [[("P", "P"), ("Q","Q")], ("K", "K"), ("Z", "Z")], 
                'Stage_Name' : ["P", "K", "Z"],  
                'Block_Name' : ["A", "B", "A"]})
```

Essentially I want to merge `Metrics` and `Stage_Name`:

[image]

Into another columns called `merged`, and for example, the 1st row would be:

```
{'P': [('P', 'P'), ('Q', 'Q')]}
```

I know how to convert one row into a dictionary representation, however, I'm not sure how do I do this to all rows without a for loop:

```
something = df.iloc[[0]].set_index('Stage_Name')['Metrics'].to_dict()
print something
Output: {'P': [('P', 'P'), ('Q', 'Q')]}
```

Later I would want to aggregate based on `Block_Name`, so for a merged column, the result would be two dictionaries added together for `Block_Name` : `A`.

```
{'P': [('P', 'P'), ('Q', 'Q')], 'Z' : [('Z', 'Z')] }
```

For `Stage_Name` and `Metrics`, I'll just have it appended to a list, which looks like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['Block_Name'])
df_2 = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

[image]

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC correctly then you use `apply` with a `lambda`:

```
In [19]:
df['merged'] = df.apply(lambda row: {row['Stage_Name']:row['Metrics']}, axis=1)
df

Out[19]:
  Block_Name           Metrics Stage_Name                           merged
0          A  [(P, P), (Q, Q)]          P  {'P': [('P', 'P'), ('Q', 'Q')]}
1          B            (K, K)          K                {'K': ('K', 'K')}
2          A            (Z, Z)          Z                {'Z': ('Z', 'Z')}
```

Comment: You can only use `axis=1` on dfs, not on `Series` this operates row-wise allowing you to access the separate columns

Answer (score 8):

```
df['Merged'] = [{key: val} for key, val in zip(df.Stage_Name, df.Metrics)]

>>> df
  Block_Name           Metrics Stage_Name                                Merged
0          A  [(P, P), (Q, Q)]          P  {u'P': [(u'P', u'P'), (u'Q', u'Q')]}
1          B            (K, K)          K                  {u'K': (u'K', u'K')}
2          A            (Z, Z)          Z                  {u'Z': (u'Z', u'Z')}
```

And then your code produces the desired result:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['Block_Name'])
df_2 = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))[['Metrics', 'Stage_Name']]


>>> df_2
                               Metrics Stage_Name
Block_Name                                       
A           ([(P, P), (Q, Q)], (Z, Z))     (P, Z)
B                            ((K, K),)       (K,)
```

Timing:

```
%timeit df['Merged'] = [{key: val} for key, val in zip(df.Stage_Name, df.Metrics)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 162 µs per loop

%timeit df['merged'] = df.apply(lambda row: {row['Stage_Name']:row['Metrics']}, axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 332 µs per loop
```

Comment: @Alexandar, this way works, however, this is also the way I'm trying to avoid, since I think it's best to use panda's built-in vectorized functions.

Comment: @user1157751 A common misperception.  See performance results above.

Comment: @Alexandar, oh wow, I didn't expect that list concatenation externally would be faster.